# Android Listview Items fill-parent whit weight

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I got this listview:

```
            <ListView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/listView2"
                android:divider="#CCCCCC"
                android:dividerHeight="1px"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
```

In the listview i will load a linearlayout:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff"/>
```

In that LinearLayout i got a weight of 1, so when the list loads it will get divided equally between all the items. Now the problem is this doesn't work, is this even possible whit weight and loading items in the listview?

Comment: I don't think this will work - I don't think listview items "know" about other items in the list...which is a requirement for your layout_weight between items to work. But I'll let someone prove me wrong.

Comment: fill_parent is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and is replaced by match_parent.

Answer (score 1):

**weight property is for LinearLayout**. **Your parent layout should be LinearLayout.** So I don't think the code that you have written is possible scenario.

Whenever you specify weight either width or height should be set to 0dp.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="5">

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:text="2" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: fill_parent is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and is replaced by match_parent.